# why does having ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub cause GUI dialog asking for SSH password even though SSH_ASKPASS is empty?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, debian, ssh-keys

**How the problem started**

For some reason I did not have my id_rsa.pub file in ~/.ssh. So I copied it off one of my servers to ~/.ssh/ on my machine... so that I have it, so I can copy it to servers when I want to access them using my SSH key.

**Strange behavior from SSH**

With the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file present I get a GUI popup asking me to enter my SSH password when I try connect to servers in a terminal emulator? (instead of ssh asking in the terminal as it always has)

**Workaround**

If I move the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file to another dir, then it asks for the SSH password in the terminal as normally expected.

**SSH_ASKPASS is not present or involved**

`echo "$SSH_ASKPASS"` returns nothing.
I ran `unset SSH_ASKPASS` anyway. (`unsetenv` does not exist on my machine). There is no SSH_ASKPASS variable on my machine, and it is not the determining factor, the determining factor is the presence of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub